# Tomcat Magnolia 5 admin central panel error

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, content-management-system, magnolia

Hello I am starting up Tomcat server which starts Magnolia 5 and even though there are no errors on startup, when I try to go to /.magnolia/admincentral I get an Internal server error and when I look at logs it looks like this:

> 2018-04-24 09:13:50,612 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1]
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.ServletDispatchingFilter -- Unable to load
>   servlet class info.magnolia.ui.admincentral.AdmincentralVaadinServlet
>   : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   info.magnolia.module.advancedcache.ui.app.AdvancedCacheToolsSubApp
>   [URI: ]
>   info.magnolia.objectfactory.configuration.ComponentConfigurationException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   info.magnolia.module.advancedcache.ui.app.AdvancedCacheToolsSubApp    at
>   info.magnolia.objectfactory.configuration.ComponentProviderConfigurationBuilder.classForName(ComponentProviderConfigurationBuilder.java:192)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.objectfactory.configuration.ComponentProviderConfigurationBuilder.getImplementation(ComponentProviderConfigurationBuilder.java:126)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.objectfactory.configuration.ComponentProviderConfigurationBuilder.getComponent(ComponentProviderConfigurationBuilder.java:112)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.UiComponentConfigurationAggregator$1.lambda$addComponents$0(UiComponentConfigurationAggregator.java:79)
>     at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)     at
>   info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.UiComponentConfigurationAggregator$1.addComponents(UiComponentConfigurationAggregator.java:77)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.UiComponentConfigurationAggregator.lambda$aggregate$2(UiComponentConfigurationAggregator.java:96)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
>     at
>   java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:270)
>     at
>   java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.UiComponentConfigurationAggregator.aggregate(UiComponentConfigurationAggregator.java:96)

and

> 2018-04-24 09:14:17,417 ERROR [agora-320]
>   info.magnolia.ui.admincentral.AdmincentralVaadinServlet -- An internal
>   error has occurred in the VaadinServlet. [URI:
>   /.magnolia/admincentral] javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:367)   at
>   info.magnolia.ui.admincentral.AdmincentralVaadinServlet.service(AdmincentralVaadinServlet.java:146)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.ServletDispatchingFilter.doFilter(ServletDispatchingFilter.java:148)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:65)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.virtualuri.VirtualUriFilter.doFilter(VirtualUriFilter.java:98)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.module.cache.executor.Bypass.processCacheRequest(Bypass.java:58)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.module.cache.executor.CompositeExecutor.processCacheRequest(CompositeExecutor.java:67)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.module.cache.filter.CacheFilter.doFilter(CacheFilter.java:220)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.i18n.I18nContentSupportFilter.doFilter(I18nContentSupportFilter.java:89)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.RangeSupportFilter.doFilter(RangeSupportFilter.java:77)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.security.BaseSecurityFilter.doFilter(BaseSecurityFilter.java:57)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.security.SecurityCallbackFilter.doFilter(SecurityCallbackFilter.java:84)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:59)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.security.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:94)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:59)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.module.site.filters.SiteMergeFilter.doFilter(SiteMergeFilter.java:119)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.multisite.filters.MultiSiteFilter.doFilter(MultiSiteFilter.java:110)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MultiChannelFilter.doFilter(MultiChannelFilter.java:83)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.module.cache.filter.GZipFilter.doFilter(GZipFilter.java:73)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:59)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.security.auth.login.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:127)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.enterprise.registration.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:64)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.personalization.preview.filter.PreviewFilter.doFilter(PreviewFilter.java:92)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:59)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.ContentTypeFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeFilter.java:155)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:128)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:65)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.SafeDestroyMgnlFilterWrapper.doFilter(SafeDestroyMgnlFilterWrapper.java:107)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterDispatcher.doDispatch(MgnlFilterDispatcher.java:67)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlMainFilter.doFilter(MgnlMainFilter.java:108)
>     at
>   info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlMainFilter.doFilter(MgnlMainFilter.java:94)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>     at
>   com.teliasonera.agora.core.requesthandling.common.spi.ServletForwardFilter.doFilter(ServletForwardFilter.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>     at
>   com.teliasonera.agora.core.requestinfo.impl.RequestInfoFilter.doFilter(RequestInfoFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:789)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleExceptionDuringRequest(VaadinService.java:1469)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1426)
>     at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:365)
>     ... 103 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException  at
>   info.magnolia.ui.admincentral.AdmincentralUI.init(AdmincentralUI.java:92)
>     at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:687)     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.getBrowserDetailsUI(UIInitHandler.java:214)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:74)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1414)
>     ... 104 more

Version of magnolia is 5.5.6 has anybody had this issue or it's project related?

Comment: Do you somehow additional trying to add advanced cache module? or what kind of a setup do you have? Firstly is it CE or EE version?

Answer (score 0):

Ilgün's question is right on here: Advanced Cache Modules are restricted to Enterprise licenses, so, if you're firing up a Community bundle, it's not going to work.

Would be nice to see some of: pom file(s), contents of WEB-INF/lib, etc.